# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Joomla Stack Exchange's [third moderator election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Harald Leithner] [image: pe7er]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! Let's also thank [FFrewin](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/126/ffrewin), who is stepping down, for their work as a moderator over the years.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5207471053340672).

Comment: A warm congratulations to our two new moderators.  I look foward to helping them with moderation tasks and discussions on how to proactively grow this community.  I also want to thank the other candidates -- I would have been just as happy if they had become my fellow moderators.  Let this stoke the fire for everyone.  The next moderator election will be here before we know it, so keep contributing and see which badges you have yet to acquire.

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators elected in this community!

Comment: And also big thanks to @FFrewin for being a great contributor/moderator in this group for years!

Comment: I would like to thank everyone that voted for me and of course thank you FFrewin for doing this job for such a long time!

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. Unfortunately, my hand is injured at the moment to write more... but I want to wish the best of luck and wisdom to the new mods.