# Upcoming moderator election in January 2023

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Joomla Stack Exchange [last had moderators elected around half a year ago](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/403/12352). After discussing it with the current moderator team, we're looking at scheduling an election to start sometime in January 2023.  This is imperative not only because [our recently graduated community](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/12352) is due for a full moderator team reboot, but also because the moderation team is below the minimum of 3 mods per team.

It should be noted that having folks willing to step up and moderate the sites is one of the few requirements we have for keeping sites alive, and given that we need to schedule an election (to bring the moderation team up to the minimum of 3 members), should it fail we'll need to have a discussion about the site's future.

But that's getting ahead of ourselves right now; to avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, I'm posting this now to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please post an answer below if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position. As I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start sometime in January 2023.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to include your whole election nomination statement.

What do diamond moderators do?

Broadly speaking, moderators handle things out of the ordinary. These include processing flags, issuing suspensions, acting as a point of contact between staff and the community, investigating vote fraud, and managing disputes, among other things. You can read more at [A Theory of Moderation on the Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) for a general overview.

What do we expect of moderators?

From looking at the moderator dashboard, the moderation workload isn't huge on Joomla. A few minutes a day should be enough time to dedicate to moderator activities. In terms of temperament, we're generally looking for people who can communicate well, keep their cool, and evaluate things from an objective standpoint. Having a decent grasp of the subject matter is a definite plus, as well as having previously shown involvement in the moderation and upkeep of the site (such as helping with the review queues and flagging).

Comment: Some of the text was adapted from [this post on Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/419).

Comment: I'm interested, you can count on me

Comment: @mickmackusa I am also interested in becoming a moderator

Comment: @JNat it is February now.  Should I be adjusting this post to be more accurate?

Comment: @Carlitorweb then I guess you'd better submit your nomination quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I am delighted to see some indications of interest from the community to become leaders.

I hope we will be able to run another exciting election with lots of candidates to choose from.

For anyone interested in self-nominating to be a moderator candidate, please take this time before the election to consider and sharpen your philosophies on what kind of direction JSE should go in.

Now is the time read, vote, and post content on Joomla Stack Exchange, and perhaps more importantly, Meta Joomla Stack Exchange.

Your self-nomination speech will help us understand why you think you'll be a good moderator, but often actions speak louder than words.  Show us what you think and what you can do!